# Adding to symfony form collection of another child entity, write parent to all new childs. Symfony2/Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to extend product.

```
class ProductType extends BaseProductType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add('variantSelectionMethod', 'choice', [
                'label' => 'sylius.form.product.variant_selection_method',
                'choices' => Product::getVariantSelectionMethodLabels(),
            ])
            ->add('productOptions', 'collection', [
                'type' => 'app_product_option_type',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'button_add_label' => 'Dodaj opcje',
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

It works partially, but when i add new entity to collection, it seems that new entities from productOptions have NULL in product field.

NEXT EDIT: solved it:
Two things:
- ajax call response need to have correct name values of input boxes, or convert it via jquery to correct
- ajax call was appended in wrong place, it should be two levels below. Also it's very important to have 
    ->add('productOptions', 'collection', [
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ])
it's easy to forget

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been a long time since my last time . I'm "a little bit" ;-) rusty.

Comment: Could you please show relative code inside entities (adder, getter...)? Wht do you mean by  `when i add new entity to collection`? Any code that shows this?

Comment: did you tried `$this->productOptions[] = $productOption;return $this;` instead of `$this->productOptions->add(productOption)`?

Comment: Please to give  another edit with the code inside controller please.

Comment: Here's the thing. It's using sylius controller "magic", and i can't show you  where is it actually saving becouse i don't know. There is additional layers and becouse of it i tagged it with sylius tag :-/